# I need some help understanding simple complexity

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain how quadratic v2 is a quadratic and any other small details that might be important in the other functions? I thought the variable passed through had to be called in twice for it to be quadratic.

```
def linear(L):
  index = 0
  while index < len(L):
    index = index + 1

def linear_v2(L):
  index1 = 0
  while index1 < len(L):
    index2 = 0
    while index2 < 1000000:
        index2 += 1
    index1 += 1

def quadratic(L):
  index1 = 0
  while index1 < len(L):
    index2 = 0
    while index2 < len(L):
        index2 += 1
    index1 += 1

def quadratic_v2(L):
  index1 = 0
  while index1 < len(L):
    index2 = 0
    while index2 < index1:
        index2 += 1
    index1 += 1


def cubic(L):
  index = 0
  while index < len(L):
    index2 = 0
    while index2 < len(L):
        index3 = 0
        while index3 < len(L):
            index3 += 1
        index2 += 1
    index +=1

def log(L):
  index = 0
  while 2 ** index < len(L):
    index += 1 

def exponential(L):
  index = 0
  while index < 2 ** len(L):
    index +=1
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Remove the back ticks, highlight the code, and press ctrl+K. And please explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`quadratic_v2` is quadratic because the content of the inner loop will still execute in quadratic proportion to the length of L. The coefficient is smaller than in the function `quadratic` but it's nonetheless quadratic.

You might imagine that if we increase the length of L, two loops are impacted. Both the outer one and the inner one. The inner one is impacted less than with `quadratic` but it still is, since `index1` becomes larger.

The content of the inner loop in `quadratic_v2` will, for length of L **n**, be called in the first loop of outer loop 1 time, in the second loop of outer loop 2 times, etc. All calls will be then:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
```

We can write this summation also as `n * (n + 1) / 2` which is equal to `1/2 n^2 + 1/2n`. This means the function is `O(n^2)`.